# I have problem with 2nd input it show word "None". how delete it

Tags: python, printing, character

```
print(input("Enter invoice number :- "))
t=0

for x in range (1,5,1):
  p=int(input(print("Enter",x,"st ",end='')))
  print(p)
  t+=p
  print("product",x," price = ",p)


print("Total Bill = ",t)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem here and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `p=int(input(print("Enter",x,"st ",end='')))`, the print function does not return anything so what is is happening is you are printing "Enter 1 st" then printing None as print return None.

To fix:

```
p=int(input("Enter " + str(x) + " st "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
p=int(input(print("Enter",x,"st ",end='')))
```

to:

```
prompt = "Enter {}st ".format(x)
p = int(input(prompt))
```

`input` prints its argument, so you don't need to call `print` when passing an argument as a prompt.  If you do, then `print` will print it, and will then return `None`, which `input` will then print.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```py
print(input("Enter invoice number :- "))
t=0


for x in range(1, 5):
  string = "Enter " + str(x) + "st "
  p = int(input(string))
  print(p)
  t+=p
  print("product", x, " price = ", p)


print("Total Bill = ",t)
```